# What is wrong with my perl script? Trying to count using hashes

Tags: perl

So I have a file with 2 columns. I want to find all unique patterns in column 2 of the file, how many times the patterns occur and their corresponding partners in column 1 of the file.

So below is a sample of my file, column 1 and 2 are separated by a tab:

```
OG5_126538  01111111111110  
OG5_126539  01110111110100  
OG5_126552  10000000000000  
OG5_126558  11111111111111  
OG5_126561  11111010000111  
OG5_126566  01111011101001  
OG5_126569  11111111111110  
OG5_126570  11111111111110  
OG5_126572  11111111111110
```

Pattern "11111111111110" occurs 3 times in column 2 and it's associated partners in column 1 are "OG5_126572, OG5_126570, OG5_126569". I want this information for all the unique patterns in column 2.

I wrote a perl program which is pasted below. But I kept getting errors. I'm new with programming. What is wrong with my program? Thanks for all the help in advance.
Perl program:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

if ( @ARGV < 1 ) {
    print "usage: matrix.pl filename\n";
    die;
}

my $my_file = shift;

my (%matrix_pattern);

open( SOURCE, $my_file );

while (<SOURCE>) {
    chomp;
    my ( $group, $pattern ) = split( "\t", $_ );
    $matrix_pattern{$group} = $pattern;
    $matrix_pattern{$pattern}++;
}

my @unique = values(%matrix_pattern);
my @sorted_unique = sort @unique;
foreach my $unique (@sorted_unique) {
    my $test = $matrix_pattern{$unique};
    print "$unique $test\n";
}

close SOURCE;
```

Below is the output from the program:

```
01110111110100 1  
01111011101001 1  
01111111111110 1  
Use of uninitialized value $test in concatenation (.) or string at matrix_sample.pl line 27, <SOURCE> line 9.  
1   
Use of uninitialized value $test in concatenation (.) or string at matrix_sample.pl line 27, <SOURCE> line 9.  
1   
Use of uninitialized value $test in concatenation (.) or string at matrix_sample.pl line 27, <SOURCE> line 9.  
1   
Use of uninitialized value $test in concatenation (.) or string at matrix_sample.pl line 27, <SOURCE> line 9.  
1   
Use of uninitialized value $test in concatenation (.) or string at matrix_sample.pl line 27, <SOURCE> line 9.  
1   
Use of uninitialized value $test in concatenation (.) or string at matrix_sample.pl line 27, <SOURCE> line 9.  
1   
10000000000000 1  
11111010000111 1  
11111111111110 3  
11111111111110 3  
11111111111110 3  
11111111111111 1  
Use of uninitialized value $test in concatenation (.) or string at matrix_sample.pl line 27, <SOURCE> line 9.  
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the `values` of a hash as the keys.  This is the source of your warnings.

A simpler solution that solves your goal is to use a hash of arrays:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fh = \*DATA;

my %matrix;

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($group, $pattern) = split ' ';
    push @{$matrix{$pattern}}, $group;
}

for my $pattern (sort keys %matrix) {
    print $pattern . ' for ' . @{$matrix{$pattern}} . " times.  Values are @{$matrix{$pattern}}\n";
}

__DATA__
OG5_126538 01111111111110
OG5_126539 01110111110100
OG5_126552 10000000000000
OG5_126558 11111111111111
OG5_126561 11111010000111
OG5_126566 01111011101001
OG5_126569 11111111111110
OG5_126570 11111111111110
OG5_126572 11111111111110
```

Outputs:

```
01110111110100 for 1 times.  Values are OG5_126539
01111011101001 for 1 times.  Values are OG5_126566
01111111111110 for 1 times.  Values are OG5_126538
10000000000000 for 1 times.  Values are OG5_126552
11111010000111 for 1 times.  Values are OG5_126561
11111111111110 for 3 times.  Values are OG5_126569 OG5_126570 OG5_126572
11111111111111 for 1 times.  Values are OG5_126558
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Miller. So with this line: " print $pattern . ' for ' . @{$matrix{$pattern}} . " times.  Values are @{$matrix{$pattern}}\n";  " **. @{$matrix{$pattern}} .** does the counting and **@{$matrix{$pattern}}** tells me what is being counted?

Comment: If you use an array in a [`scalar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/scalar.html) context, it returns the number of elements.  That's what the concatenation operator `.` does.  However, if you interpolate an array, it joins the elements using the value of [`$"`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24LIST_SEPARATOR) which defaults to a space.